# Cancel a UILongPressGestureRecognizer after a certain time

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uigesturerecognizer

I used a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` in my `UICollectionView`. Now I when I hold my finger on the CollectionView items after a certain amount of time (for example 1 second), I want my `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` to end and execute a certain code:

```
if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {}
```

This is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  Public = [[PublicMethods alloc]init];
  self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
  [self.view addSubview:self.collect];

  UILongPressGestureRecognizer *lpgr = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongPress:)];
  lpgr.minimumPressDuration = 3; //seconds
  lpgr.delaysTouchesBegan = YES;
  lpgr.delegate = self;
  [self.collect addGestureRecognizer:lpgr];


}
-(void)handleLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
  if (gestureRecognizer.state != UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
    return;
  }

  CGPoint p = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.collect];
  NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.collect indexPathForItemAtPoint:p];
  if (indexPath == nil){
    NSLog(@"couldn't find index path");
  } else {
    // get the cell at indexPath (the one you long pressed)
    //CollectionViewCell* cell = (CollectionViewCell*)[self.collect cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"bala" message:@"jalaaaa" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey, did you want it to happen after 1 sec or 3 seconds since your minimumPressDuration = 3?

Comment: @LyndseyScott I want when hold my finger on collection cell after 3 second end gesture...

Comment: If you want both the `minimumPressDuration` and the maximum duration to be 3, you can simply put your ending code in a `if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {` conditional.

Comment: My current answer assumes that you want the gesture to cancel 3 seconds after it's recognized for example it would cancel in 6 seconds if the gesture starts 3 seconds after the user begins pressing the screen. FYI

Comment: @LyndseyScott my friend your answer not working!!!!

Comment: @LyndseyScott my friend please help me about this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could instantiate a timer upon the start of the `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` then cancel the gesture and execute the "end gesture" code once the timer is complete, ex (using a 1 second time limit):

```
- (void)handleLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        // Create a timer that calls cancel: 2.5 second after the 
        // gesture begins (i.e. 3 seconds after the button press if
        // if lpgr.minimumPressDuration = .5;. Pass the gesture
        // recognizer along within the user info dictionary parameter.
        timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.5 target:self selector:@selector(cancel:) userInfo:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:gestureRecognizer, @"gestureRecognizer", nil] repeats:NO];

    } else if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        // Assuming you still want to execute the end code
        // if the user lifts their finger before the 3 seconds
        // is complete, use the same method called in the timer.
        [self cancel:nil];
    }
}

- (void)cancel:(NSTimer*)timerObject {

    NSLog(@"%@",[timer.userInfo objectForKey:@"gestureRecognizer"]);
    // Get the gesture recognizer from the info dictionary
    UIGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer = [timer.userInfo objectForKey:@"gestureRecognizer"];

    CGPoint p = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.collect];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.collect indexPathForItemAtPoint:p];
    if (indexPath == nil){
        NSLog(@"couldn't find index path");
    } else {
        // get the cell at indexPath (the one you long pressed)
        //CollectionViewCell* cell = (CollectionViewCell*)[self.collect cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"bala" message:@"jalaaaa" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
    }

    // Disable it and re-enable it to cancel the gesture
    gestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;
    gestureRecognizer.enabled = YES;

    // Invalidate the timer
    [timer invalidate];
    timer = nil;
}
```

Comment: my friend this answer not working. I get this massage "couldn't find index path"

Comment: @mamal10 Was that line of code ever working for you? I haven't changed that part of your code at all.

Comment: @mamal10 If it was in fact working for you before, check out my updated answer since it might make a difference. I've moved the gesture canceling code so it's after your "end gesture" code.

Comment: my friend I want when hold my finger on cell after 3 second end gesture even if I hold my finger on cell

Comment: @mamal10 Then (like I mentioned in various comments) either change your  minimumPressDuration and timer duration such that minimumPressDuration + the timer duration == 3 so the gesture is recognized automatically, or simply put your end code in an `if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) { conditional` so that once the gesture is recognized at 3 seconds (the minimumPressDuration), the code is immediately executed.

Comment: my friend I get this massage "couldn't find index path"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70616/discussion-between-lyndsey-scott-and-mamal10).

Comment: my friend this part of code : "if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)" not working I hold 10 second even more don't display me alert why?

Answer (score 0):

```
    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongPress:)];
    longPress.minimumPressDuration = 0.4; // !!! Your certain time
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:longPress];
    
    - (void)handleLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gesture
    {
    // Catch first gesture changing and reset gesture
    if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
        if (self.delegate) {
            AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1520);
            [self.delegate call];
            gesture.enabled = NO; // Reset gesture
            gesture.enabled = YES;
        }
    }
```