# How to cancel LongPressGestureRecognizer?

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer

I have a view that has a `LongPressGestureRecognizer` assigned to it which calls the following method:

```
@IBAction func longPressOnView1Recognized(_ sender: UIGestureRecognizer) {

    if sender.state == .began {
        // this runs when user's finger is down a "long time"
    }
    if sender.state == .ended {
        // this runs when user's finger goes up again after the .began state 
    }

}
```

This all works as expected, but I'm trying to find a (good/proper) way of being able to programmatically `cancel` the long press recognizer (in certain circumstances) while the user's finger is still down.

That is, *while* a user's finger is still down on the view, and the recognizer has entered the .began state, (but *before* the user has lifted their finger -- before recognizer enters the .ended state)... is there some code we can run that will prevent the method above from firing when the user lifts their finger... like prematurely telling IOS to no longer listen for UP events for the remainder of this gesture?

I've read these [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/touches_presses_and_gestures/handling_uikit_gestures/handling_long-press_gestures), but I don't have that much experience with IOS touch, and I can't seem to find any method that is designed for this purpose.

my `GestureRecognizer.reset()` does not seem to do what I'm describing.

I can think of two possibilities:

1) A boolean flag, that would go inside the `if sender.state == .ended {}` closure

2) this:

```
myLongPressRecognizer.isEnabled = false
myLongPressRecognizer.isEnabled = true
```

Both of these work but seem not so great.

Comment: see this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28414690/cancel-a-uilongpressgesturerecognizer-after-a-certain-time

Comment: Disabling a gesture recognizer is the correct way of canceling any events assigned to it. You usually want to enable it right after so those two lines under `2)` are completely valid and correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are all good with disabling and reenabling the gesture recognizer so doing

```
myLongPressRecognizer.isEnabled = false
myLongPressRecognizer.isEnabled = true
```

is completely correct.

What I am worried about is you don't completely understand gesture recognizers. You should always use switch statement when handling gesture recognizer. Check the comments:

```
func handleLongPressGestureRecognizer(_ sender: UIGestureRecognizer) {

    switch sender.state {
    case .began:
        // This will be called only once when the gesture starts
        print("Long press did begin at \(sender.location(in: sender.view))")
    case .changed:
        // This will be called whenever your finger moves (at some frequency obviously).
        // At this point your long press gesture is acting exactly the same as pan gesture
        print("Long press changed position to \(sender.location(in: sender.view))")
    case .ended:
        // This is when user lifts his finger assuming the gesture was not canceled
        print("Long press ended at \(sender.location(in: sender.view))")
    case .cancelled:
        // This is equally important as .ended case. You gesture may be canceled for many reasons like a system gesture overriding it. Make sure to implement logic here as well.
        print("Long press canceled at \(sender.location(in: sender.view))")
    case .failed, .possible:
        // These 2 have been added additionally at some point. Useless as far I am concerned.
        break
    }

}
```

So at least you should handle cancelled status. But also note that the changed status will be triggered whenever the gesture is moved.

Answer (score 2):

Nowadays, `state` is mutable. So just set the `state` to `.cancelled` and the gesture will be cancelled. The headers suggest that it is still a `get`-only property, but in practice, it actually is mutable. They must have included the import of `UIKit.UIGestureRecognizer` (discussed below) as part of the broader `import UIKit`.

---

In previous iOS versions, `state` was immutable and one had explicitly import the gesture recognizer header to make gestures cancelable:

```
import UIKit.UIGestureRecognizer
```

That would make the otherwise immutable `state` property a readwrite property. But this is no longer necessary.

Comment: Hack approach, but a valid work around. I prefer to use `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline:)` instead of a timer.

Comment: It is not a hack approach: Importing `UIKit.UIGestureRecognizer` was/is the Apple-approved technique for canceling in-progress gestures, i.e., to make `state` mutable. Now, if you don’t want to use a `Timer` to cancel the gesture, as in my example, that’s fine. That’s not really relevant (and I’ve removed this distraction from my answer). Use GCD `asyncAfter` if you want (though you’d have to use `DispatchWorkItem` rendition to make it cancelable, not the block-based interface, and it doesn’t handle cancelation nearly as gracefully as operations, async-await, timers, etc.). To each his own.

Comment: I believe anytime you have to force a thread hop with a delay to get the UI to perform as desired is "hackish". It's often ugly and not as determinate I would prefer, and says more about Swift UI idiosyncrasies. Thanks for updating the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have your solution on hand already. Toggling the `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` `isEnabled` is the best way to go. Setting the `state` property isn't possible, because it's a get-only property.

```
open var state: UIGestureRecognizer.State { get } // the current state of the gesture recognizer
```

`isEnabled` property is documented as:

> default is YES. disabled gesture recognizers will not receive touches. when changed to NO the gesture recognizer will be cancelled if it's currently recognizing a gesture.

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer to the OP's question is much simpler, just call:

```
gesture.state = .cancelled
```

Whenever you want to cancel an active gesture.
No need to toggle booleans on and off.